# Counting number of times an atom occurs in a table in J language

Tags: j

In J, to count the number of times an element occurs in a list in J is:

```
count =: 4 : '+/x=y'"0 1.
```

Alternatively, one can use the "member of interval" E. What is the equivalent expression, in J, for counting the number of times an "atom" occurs in a table?

I am also curious why the rank of "count" is given as 1 0 1, when it is specifically defined as a dyad. Why is the monad rank 1 also included? Can "count", as defined above be used as a monad?

Comment: 1. You can use `-:` for general matches. 2. Where is `1 0 1` from? I only see `"0 1`.

Comment: 1. @Eelvex, I don't understand what you mean by using -: for general matches to count the number of "atoms" in a table. Could you please elaborate? 2. My question regarding the rank of "count=: 4 : '+/x-y' " 0 1" was really trying to understand how it works on nouns, based on its defined rank (count b.0) given by J as 1 0 1 - where the first 1 is the monadic rank of the verb count and the 0 1 referring to the left and right ranks of the dyadic case. If "count" is specifically defined as a dyad (i.e. 4:'+/x=y' "0 1) then why is there a monadic rank still assigned to the verb as well?

Comment: 1. I missread your question. 2. The monadic rank appears as `1` with `b.` because you implicitly assigned it so (monadic rank = right dyadic rank, unless explicitly assigned). In other words `"a, b` reads as `"b,a,b`.

Comment: Ok, @Eelvex. Thanks. I did not know that monadic rank = right dyadic rank in dyadic verb rank assingment.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is to make the table into a list using (Ravel) monadic ','and then proceed as before. So count becomes:

```
count=: +/@: (= ,) NB. tacit
count=: 4 : '+/ x = ,y'  NB. explicit
```

Cheers, bob

Comment: Thanks @bob. I didn't think of ravel. I was thinking of ways of manipulating the rank of the verb "count" in order to get it to work. on tables.

Comment: bob's solution is better (generalises to arrays of any rank), but another option for tables is `count=: 4 :'+/+/x=y'"0 1`

Comment: In reply to ADO: Count or Tally (`#`) may be applied at any rank you wish, but that also determines what it counts. Since you want to count atoms you want to do so with a list of atoms. If you wished to count rows, you'd do so with a table (which is a list of rows.) If you wished to count tables, you'd apply Tally to a list of tables, a.k.a. a report. These are the sorts of options Rank allows you to choose among.